# PDO prepare - binding values

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a PDO DB class that's made by a tutorial. 
There is a method in it that binds values when i send an insert query, in fact here it is:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()){

    $this->_error = false;

    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){

        if(count($params)){

            $x = 1;
            foreach($params as $param){

                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;

            }

        }

        if($this->_query->execute()){

            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();

        } else{

            $this->_error = true;

        }

    }

    return $this;

}
```

The problem that i have is that i don't really understand how this binding works, i'm sending this query:

```
DB::instance()->query("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (<script>alert('test');</script>)");
```

Here is my instance() method:

```
public static function instance(){

    if(!isset(self::$_instance)){

        self::$_instance = new DB();

    }

    return self::$_instance;

}
```

Now the problem is that after i enter that alert test in the database table and then i get fetch that row that alert is jumping up like a very crazy rabbit :(.

My question is: isn't this a very basic sql injection? Why am i able to enter scripts like that one into the database and how do i display those kind of values without actually executing that script?

Thank youuu! :D

Comment: Your query isn't valid SQL, it needs quotes around `<script>alert('test');</script>)`.

Comment: `INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (<script>alert('test');</script>)` is  a pseudo query? It sounds like you are concerned with XSS injections if you are wondering why the `alert(..)` executes...but for that to be stored the query would first need to be valid.

Comment: It's an XSS vulnerability and not SQL injection. The database has nothing to do with it at all.

Comment: @Dormilich SQL injection could be relevant, OP doesn't appear to be using `$param` so it also would be SQL injectable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no SQL injection in your code, since `<script>alert('test');</script>` is not SQL.

Prepared statements only prevent SQL injection if you use them properly -- it's a tool that makes it easier to write safe code, not a magic bullet that checks what you're doing. You have to supply all the untrusted data through the `$params` array, not by substituting it into the query. So you should do:

```
$DB::instance()->query("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (?)", ["<script>alert('test');</script>"]);
```

BTW, it's not necessary to call `bindValue()` in a loop. The `execute()` method can be given an array of parameters as its argument, so you can just do:

```
$this->_query->execute($params);
```

To prevent the Javascript from being executed if you display the column in an HTML web page, use `htmlentities()`:

```
echo htmlentities($row['column'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

This prevents Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.

Comment: Hey Barmar, thank you for your answer. That way when i output that result i'm getting that alert test, should i escape that value before sending it to the database? Thank you! :D

Comment: No, you should encode it with `htmlentities()` before displaying on a web page. There's nothing special about HTML and Javascript in databases.

Comment: And overall it is secure agains sql injections? :-s(sorry for bothering youX_X)

Comment: The parametrized query protects against SQL injection. htmlentities protects against XSS. They're totally independent.

Comment: I think `ENT_QUOTES` should be used with the `htmlentities`

Comment: @chris85 Depends on where you're echoing it, although there's no harm in using it always. You need it when echoing into an HTML attribute.